# UseEffect hook error, Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to set state in my useEffect hook when the appState is active, however, I get the warning. How can I set state when my app is active?

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
      "change",
      async (nextAppState) => {
        if (
          appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
          nextAppState === "active"
        ) {
          setAppStateVisible(true); // set state to true
        }

        appState.current = nextAppState;
        setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Are there any `await`s in your `async` function? I don't see any in the question, but perhaps you simplified it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you *are* removing (cancelling) your subscription in a cleanup callback, I'm guessing you probably have one or more `await`s in your `async` function (otherwise, why make it an `async` function?) though you haven't shown any. Since the `await`s mean that your code pauses then continues again later (when the promise it's `await`ing is settled), you need to allow for the possibility your component has been unmounted in the meantime.

Ideally, `subscription` would have a way for you to check if it's been removed (like `AbortSignal`'s `aborted` flag). I can't find any documentation for it, though; [`AppState.addEventListener`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#addeventlistener) says it's an `EventSubscription`, but doesn't provide a link, and I can't find any docs for `EventSubscription`.

If it has one, you want to use it. Otherwise, you can add a simple flag in addition to your code removing the subscription:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;                              // ***
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
        "change",
        async (nextAppState) => {
            if (cancelled) {                            //
                return;                                 // ***
            }                                           //
            if (
                appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
                nextAppState === "active"
            ) {
                setAppStateVisible(true); // set state to true
            }

            await something();                          // Example of an `await`
            if (cancelled) {                            //
                return;                                 // ***
            }                                           //
    
            appState.current = nextAppState;
            setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
        }
    );

    return () => {
        cancelled = true;                               // ***
        subscription.remove();
    };
}, []);
```

If you *don't* have any `await`s, it would appear that React Native has some race condition where it may still call your subscription callback even after you've done a `remove` on it, which would be less than ideal. The above will handle that, too.

Having a `cancelled` flag like that **on its own** is often considered an anti-pattern (better to cancel the subscription than just ignore the call), but that's not what we're doing above. We're cancelling the subscription *and* dealing with the possibility the code is called or continues after the subscription is cancelled, which is fine.

If you can't find a flag on `EventSubscription`, you might consider giving yourself a wrapper for it so you can reuse this easily:

```
function subscribeAppState(fn) {
    const subscription = AppState.subscribe(fn);
    return {
        remove() {
            subscription.remove();
            this.removed = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Then:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const sub = subscribeAppState(
        "change",
        async (nextAppState) => {
            if (sub.removed) {                          //
                return;                                 // ***
            }                                           //
            if (
                appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
                nextAppState === "active"
            ) {
                setAppStateVisible(true); // set state to true
            }

            await something();                          // Example of an `await`
            if (sub.removed) {                          //
                return;                                 // ***
            }                                           //
    
            appState.current = nextAppState;
            setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
        }
    );

    return () => {
        sub.remove();
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is a common problem in React that has no official solution as of yet (AFAIK).

You can do something like this (it works, but half of the Internet see this as anti-pattern):

```
useEffect(() => {
   let isMounted = true;
   const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", 
      async (nextAppState) => {
    if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active" && isMounted) { 
        setAppStateVisible(true); // set state to true
    }

    appState.current = nextAppState;

    if(isMounted) {
        setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    }

    });

  return () => {
    isMounted = false;
    subscription.remove();
  };
}, []);
```

Basically the idea is to wrap your setAppStateVisible calls in a protective check whether the component is mounted or not - because you should not update the state of the component if it is unmounted (as the message says).

Comment: The flag *on its own* would be considered (by some) to be an anti-pattern, but not this. This is also cancelling the subscription. The flag's just there because (apparently) the function gets called despite the subscription having been removed. (I suspect because the OP's cut down the code for the question and they are using `await`.)